# If a cell has a value, display text?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to display text in a cell if another cell has a value.
I can do this successfully, however it adds an extra space that I can't have

One column has a unit number, the next column has an address field. I am combining the 2 together with a - in between
e.g.

- Column M has the unit (e.g. 123
- Column N has the address (e.g 12345 Sample St)
- Column O has the formula =if(M1, "-",)

Column F has `=M1&""&O1 &N1`

The result is

- 123 -12345 Sample St
  without the entry in column M the result also has a space in front of the 1234 Sample St
  I'm trying to achieve a result without a space between 123 and 12345 Sample St (123-12345 Sample St)

How would I do this?

Comment: Your post says that address entries begin in Row 1, whereas Row 1 typically had header text. What is the actual case in your sheet?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
`=M1&O1&N1`

There's no need for the quotation marks in your existing formula, and I think this is where the error is creeping in.

**TROUBLESHOOTING**

- `=len(M1)` - the result should be 3
- `=len(N1)` - the result should be 15
- `=len(O1)` - the result should be 1

The total length of `=M1&O1&N1` should be 19.

Answer (score 1):

See my comment to your original post. For now, I'll assume that you *do* have a header in F1 and that your actual addresses begin in Row 2.

Select Col F and delete everything (including the header).

In F1, place the following formula:

`=ArrayFormula({"Full Street Address"; IF(N2:N="",,IF(M2:M="",,TRIM(M2:M)&"-")&TRIM(N2:N))})`

You don't need Col O at all.

This one formula should produce the header (which you can *within the formula itself* as you like) and all results for all rows.